# Calculadora JavaScript Con la Tecla DEL

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Solo quisiera borrar, cuando me confundo en algo no que borre todo, no sabria como ponerlo me podrias ayudar. Ya tendria puesto la funcion pero no se como podria ponerlo.

La tecla DEL borra el valor del operando actual, o sea seria asi, como lo pongo.

Pongo el codigo pero no me va y ya lotengo mencionado en el html.

```js
//Variables
  
  var a;
  var b;
  var c;
  var d;
  var f;

  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;

  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var division = document.getElementById("division");
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
  var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
  var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
  var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
  var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
  var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
  var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
  var cero = document.getElementById("cero");
  var coma = document.getElementById("coma");
  var borradoParcial = document.getElementById("borradoParcial");//Este seria la tecla DEL.

//Eventos

function init() {
  uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
  }  
  seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
  }  
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
  }
  coma.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + ".";
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Resetear
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Retroceder(Tecla DEL)
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  borradoParcial.onclick = function(e){
    retroceder();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // Operaciones
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar1(a);
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar2(b);
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar3(c);
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar4(d);
  }
  verificar.onclick = function(e){
    operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar1(a){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "+";
}
function limpiar2(b){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "-";
}
function limpiar3(c){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "*";
}
function limpiar4(d){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "/";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resetear(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operandoa = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}

//------------------------------------------------
//Tecla DEL
//------------------------------------------------

$('html').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 8) {
    var val = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
    if(val.length > 0){
        val = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = val;
    }
}
});

//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = "";
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob == 0){
        res = 0;
        window.alert("ERROR");
      } else {
        res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-              FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">   </script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
   <header class="top">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
   </header>
   <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li>DEL</li>
        <li id="reset" onclick="init()">C</li>
        <li id="borradoParcial" onclick="init()"></li>
    <li id="siete" onclick="init()">7</li>
    <li id="ocho" onclick="init()">8</li>
    <li id="nueve" onclick="init()">9</li>
    <li id="division"onclick="init()">&frasl;</li>
    <li id="cuatro" onclick="init()">4</li>
    <li id="cinco" onclick="init()">5</li>
    <li id="seis" onclick="init()">6</li>
    <li id="multiplicacion" onclick="init()">*</li>
    <li id="uno" onclick="init()">1</li>
    <li id="dos" onclick="init()">2</li>
    <li id="tres" onclick="init()">3</li>
    <li id="resta" onclick="init()">-</li>
    <li id="cero" onclick="init()">0</li>
    <li id="coma" onclick="init()">.</li>
    <li id="suma" onclick="init()">+</li>
    <li id="verificar" onclick="init()">=</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar esto

```js
$('html').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 8) {
        var val = document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
        if(val.length > 0){
            val = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = val;
        }
    }
});
```

Con esto oprimes la tecla borrar y elimina el ultimo carácter del texto de la cadena

Comment: lo impolemento pero no me funciona tu codigo como lo podria implementar

Comment: Añadiste la librería de JQuery? el listener del keyup es de JQuery debes implementar la librería en tu código. o cual error es el que te muestra?

Comment: No lo tengo puesto pero no se como ponerlo

Comment: Solo agrega este código abajo de donde haces referencia a tu css <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Sigue sin ir el codigo, y ya lo mencione lo repunlique con el codigo que me diste para saber donde me esta fallando.

Comment: Agrega el http:// antes del src de la libreria de jquery porque asi como esta, lo interpreta que tienes una carpeta con ese nombre, te paso el script solo quita el espacio entre // y code.jquery, <script src="http:// code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>